Identifying only records that changed in Power BI
I have the following table in Power BI, this table gets its data from Excel files stored in a folder that contains daily extracts from a source system. Sometimes users change records in the source system and we need to be able to identify which records were changed and which value or values in those records were changed, from what value to what value. How can we do that in power bi?
Here is the sample table

Here is the expected output that I am looking for.

Thank you, for your assistance!

In Power Query you can merely group by Order Number. If there is more than one order in the Group, examine which comes from the later Source and extract the changed column. If you need assistance with the code, edit your question to show your data as text which can be copy/pasted. See: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Sadly, tracking changes like this is not possible in Power BI, it is not a database, for which this use case is suited for

I don't know how to do this with Power BI, but if you make the daily extract (I presume some sort of script) save both the new and previous day's Excel files as .CSV's, you can identify the changes with a simple diff.

Given that your table in PQ apparently has data from multiple files, you can tell if there has been a change by:

Group by Order Number
If there is more than one row in a group, then there has been a change
Create your results table from the subgroup in the aggregation as shown below.
Assumptions as you did not provide relevant information:

If there are changes in more than one column, output the information on separate rows
(I showed this in my sample)
If there are multiple changes, the code as written will show the change from the first to the last entry. If you want something different, be specific
the Source files will be listed in date order.

If not, a Sort will need to be added.





let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Order number", type text}, {" Order Date", type date}, 
        {"Category", type text}, {"Description", type text},
        {"Buyer", type text}, {"Source.Name", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Order number"}, {
        {"Changes",(t)=> 
            let
                #"Mismatched Columns" = List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), (col)=>
                    if List.Count(List.Distinct(Table.Column(t,col)))>1 then col else null)),
                #"Select Cols" = Table.SelectColumns(t,#"Mismatched Columns"),
                #"Change Date" = Date.From(Text.SplitAny(List.Last(t[Source.Name]),"_."){1}),
                #"Changed Cols" = List.RemoveLastN(#"Mismatched Columns",1),
                #"Changed Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(t, #"Changed Cols"),
                Fields = {"ChangedColumns","OldValue","NewValue","ChangeDate"},
                #"Records" = List.Accumulate(
                    #"Changed Cols",
                    {},
                    (s,c)=> s &  
                        {Record.FromList({c, 
                                          List.First(Table.Column(#"Changed Columns",c)), 
                                          List.Last(Table.Column(#"Changed Columns",c)), 
                                          #"Change Date"},Fields)}) 
            in 
               Table.FromRecords( #"Records"),type table[ChangedColumns=text,OldValue=any, NewValue=any,ChangeDate=date]
                }}),
    #"Expanded Changes" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Changes", {"ChangedColumns", "OldValue", "NewValue", "ChangeDate"}, {"ChangedColumns", "OldValue", "NewValue", "ChangeDate"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Changes", each ([ChangedColumns] <> null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"


